# Image seralization is about 30x size

Tags: java, image, serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object that contains an `ImageIcon` (which implements serializable). That image is a sample image of ubuntu, is about 320k size.

```
public static void write() {
    ImageIcon aww = null;
    aww = new ImageIcon("/home/javi/PRUEBA/img.jpg");
    ab hue = new ab("hola", "adios", 10, 1111, aww);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    FileOutputStream a = null;
    try {
        a = new FileOutputStream("/home/javi/PRUEBA/mapa.atd");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(a);
        oos.writeObject(hue);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            a.close();
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ab implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4377893644898458425L;

    String asdf;
    String b;
    int w;
    Integer ab;
    ImageIcon a;
    public ab(String asdf, String b, int w, Integer ab, ImageIcon ww) {
        super();
        this.asdf = asdf;
        this.b = b;
        this.w = w;
        this.ab = ab;
        a = ww;
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm using, and I don't know why the image is about 320k and the output file is about 10Mb. If needed I can upload the img (`/usr/share/unity-2d/warty-final-ubuntu.jpg`
)

Comment: Using descriptive variable names would help us help you!

Comment: @KevinBrydon the names are just random names, it works perfectly but the output file is 10Mb, that sounds really big for a serialization of a 320k img

Comment: You need to close 'oos', and not 'a'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image data stored in the ImageIcon is probably a simple, non-compressed bitmap equivalent. An array of ints, possibly.

If you want to efficiently use the java serialization, you have to write a wrapper around this class and store the original binary file in the memory and mark the ImageIcon as `transient` - and rebuild the ImageIcon from the data when it is necessary after the deserialization.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it. (I'll accept the answer once I can!)

Comment: way better than my answer

Answer (score 1):

what's the problem. i think the serialization method of `ImageIcon` is treat the image as uncompressed bitmap. and uncompressed bitmap is much bigger than compressed one.